# Rails: How to pass value "9999-99-99" to date if checkbox is checked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, datepicker

I have a datepicker to :DATE and a "Unknown" checkbox aside. I need to pass "9999-99-99" to :DATE if checkbox is checked.

Here is my code.

```
1    <%= form.label :DATE %>
2    <%= form.datepicker :DATE %>
3    <div>
4      <label class="radio-inline"> <%=  form.check_box :DATE %> Unknown </label>
5    </div>
```

I also got an error for line 4:

`undefined method 'to_i' for Thu, 19 Dec 2019:Date
 Did you mean?  to_s`.

In my database, :DATE is formatted as "YYYY-MM-DD".

Thanks.

Comment: Is `9999-99-99` even a date?

Comment: @RajdeepSingh no it is not. Wendy just handle this in the controller `form.checkbox :unknown_date` then `if params[:wrapper][:unknown_date] #do something here`

Answer (score 1):

You can't save a date value as **9999-99-99** cause it is not a **date** when you run the following in *irb* in terminal

```
Date.new(9999,99,99)
```

it will throw the following error.

> ArgumentError (invalid date)